# Video is not supported in html5

Tags: html, video

I have the latest FF and I am trying to embed a video using the video tag. I saved the file on my desktop with test.html and my video is also at the desktop 
This is the code I'm using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video controls>

  <source src="Wildlife.wmv">
  Your browser doesn't support video, you may download the

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error `No video with supported format and MIME type found.`

Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers don't use wmv as the codec isn't widely avaliable - use mp4, ogg or webm depending on the browser.

http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody is a brilliant resource for learning about the intricacies here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 <body>

 <object width="50%" height="50%" type="video/x-ms-asf" url="Wildlife.wmv" data="Wildlife.wmv" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
 <param name="url" value="Wildlife.wmv">
 <param name="filename" value="Wildlife.wmv">
 <param name="autostart" value="1">
 <param name="uiMode" value="full" />
 <param name="autosize" value="1">
 <param name="playcount" value="1"> 
 <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="Wildlife.wmv" width="100%" height="100%" autostart="true" showcontrols="true"      pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
 </object>

</body>
```

Comment: we can do this in html4 too then what is benefit of video tag in HTML5

Comment: ".wmv" video files are not supported by any browser. That is the only way for WMV video files. If not, then change the extension of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are running your application on various user agents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <video controls>

      <source src="Wildlife.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="Wildlife.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="Wildlife.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser doesn't support video, you may download the

    </video>
    </body>
    </html>
```